# Vagrant 1.3.3 and Virtualbox 4.0.8 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, vagrant

I am able to get Vagrant to communicate with Virtualbox without any problems (using Vbox headless and VBoxManage). However for some reason, the VM failed to boot up. When I try to bring it manually from Virtualbox, it just gives me a black screen with no indication of a presence of linux image. There is no communication (from vagrant) after trying to boot-up presumably because the VM isnt booting. It just times-out.

I tried with several vagrant boxes but same result. (Ubuntu Images - quantal and precise)

**Versions**

- Vagrant 1.3.3
- Virtualbox 4.0.8 +4.2.18
- Windows 7

Comment: Have you turned on Virtualization in the bios? Its strange that you are not getting any messages from starting the machine through virtual box manually though... I would double check that and if there are no messages then reinstall virtual box.

Comment: In addition to turning on VT-x/AMD-V in BIOS, try to enable virtualbox gui in Vagrantfile and enable debug => `VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up` to see why it's failing.

Comment: Perfect @MattCooper and @TerryWang!! You both answered both my questions, it works right. Just needed to run as administrator to avoid running into problems.